# Execution will likely fail Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "stack limit reached 1024 (1023)" } On The Polygon Network

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate, polygon

I have been working on this Flashloan arbitrage and when I call the execute operation function I get `Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "stack limit reached 1024 (1023)" }`
after doing some research I learned it has something to do with gas fees and the stack limit I don't know what is causing it though here is the flashloan code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import { ILendingPool, ILendingPoolAddressesProvider, IERC20 } from "./Interfaces.sol";
import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Router } from "./Arbitrage.sol";
import { Withdrawable } from "./Withdrawable.sol";  
import { MoneyPrinter } from "MoneyPrinter.sol";
import { SafeMath } from "./Libraries.sol";
import { Ownable } from "Ownable.sol";

/** 
!!!
Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanReceiverBase contract as they could be 
exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.
!!!
*/

contract DexArbitrageFlashloan is FlashLoanReceiverBase, Ownable, Withdrawable {
event UpdatedArbitrageContract (address oldArbitrageContract, address 
newArbitrageContract);
using SafeMath for uint256;

address _token2;
address _router1;
address _router2;
MoneyPrinter arbitrageContract;
address Dai  = 0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063; 

constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider) FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider) {
    arbitrageContract = MoneyPrinter(arbitrageContract);}

function params(address _router1, address _router2, address _token2) public onlyOwner {}

/**
    This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
 */


function executeOperation(
    address[] calldata assets,
    uint256[] calldata amounts,
    uint256[] calldata premiums
    // address initiator
   // bytes calldata params
)
    public onlyOwner
    override
    returns (bool)
{

    // This contract now has the funds requested.
    // Your logic goes here.

    DexArbitrageFlashloan.flashloan(
    address(Dai),
     uint256(10) 
    );

    arbitrageContract.DualDexArbitrage(
    address(Dai),
    address(_router1),
    address(_router2),
    address(_token2),
    uint256(1)
    );

    // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
    // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.
    // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
    // these amounts.
    // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount

    for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
        IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
    }

    return true;
}


/*
 *  Flash loan wei amount worth of `_asset`
 */

function flashloan(address _asset, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
   // bytes memory data = "";
    uint amount = _amount;

    address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
    assets[0] = _asset;

    uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
    amounts[0] = amount;

    flashloan(_asset, _amount);

}

    function setArbitrageContract (address _newArbitrageContract) public onlyOwner {
    address _previousArbitrageContract = address(arbitrageContract);
    arbitrageContract = MoneyPrinter(_newArbitrageContract);
    emit UpdatedArbitrageContract (_previousArbitrageContract, _newArbitrageContract);
   }

}
```

I'm on the Polygon Network if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there did you get this code, but its totally wrong, please [start from this sample of AAVE Flashloan.](https://github.com/aave/code-examples-protocol/blob/main/V2/Flash%20Loan%20-%20Batch/MyV2FlashLoan.sol) [And read AAVE Flashloan documentation carefully](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/guides/flash-loans#overview)

Comment: the code has been edited to fit my needs if I remove the arbitrage logic the flashloan works perfectly

Comment: also the original code with no-arbitrage logic is from the save flash loan documentation